# Running spark streaming forever on production

Tags: linux, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am developing a spark streaming application which basically reads data off kafka and saves it periodically to HDFS.

I am running pyspark on YARN.

My question is more for production purpose. Right now, I run my application like this:

`spark-submit stream.py`

Imagine you are going to deliver this spark streaming application (in python) to a client, what would you do in order to keep it running forever? You wouldn't just give this file and say "Run this on the terminal". It's too unprofessional.

What I want to do , is to submit the job to the cluster (or processors in local) and never have to see logs on the console, or use a solution like [linux screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) to run it in the background (because it seems too unprofessional).

What is the most professional and efficient way to permanently submit a spark-streaming job to the cluster ?

I hope I was unambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: is your problem to run forever even after closing the terminal ? Did you have a look at spark-submit --deploy-mode "cluster"

Comment: @Knight71, yes I have. But that doesn't solve my problem. My question is, on production, would you have a terminal perpetually open so that you are not killing the spark job? I'm sure LinkedIn or any other company using spark streaming on production, has a very good production site deployment method and i was curious to know about it.

Comment: You can close the terminal after deploying in cluster mode. The streaming will run without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use spark-jobserver which provides rest interface for uploading your jar and running it . You can find the documentation here [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) .